# Objective-C write to messages

Tags: objective-c, macos, share, message

I want to be able to write to `messages`. If more accurately - to share photo directly to `messages`, just like `preview` does. Example photo:

[image]
[image]

Is it even possible? Because I still haven't found any info about sharing to `messages`, or even `mail`.

Comment: "Is it even possible?" it probably is, since Preview does it, you just mentioned it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NSSharingService](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSSharingService_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSSharingServicePicker](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSSharingServicePicker_Class/Reference/Reference.html) classes provide functionality you need. You can start with apple's [SharingServices](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SharingServices/Introduction/Intro.html) sample to see how to use them.

Note also that that functionality is available starting OSX 10.8